# Changing the type of values of a dictionary from list to set

Tags: python, dictionary, set

I have a dictionary in python that looks like this:

```
{'Alan Turing': ['Alanin', 'Anting'], 'Donald Knuth': ['Donut'], 'Claude Shannon': ['Cannon']}
```

Now I want to change the type of values of a dictionary from list to set.

What is an easy way to do this?

Comment: `set(my_dict)`. This has to be a duplicate.

Comment: @Abdou I think you and Muntaser have misunderstood the question. `set(my_dict)` will return a set; it won't convert the dictionary values from lists into sets.

Comment: Ah! Now that makes sense. `{k:set(v) for k,v in my_dict.items()}` then.

Comment: @Abdou close: `{k:set(v) for k,v in my_dict.items()}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code will cause all dictionary values to change from lists to sets:

```
d = {'Alan Turing': ['Alanin', 'Anting'], 'Donald Knuth': ['Donut'], 'Claude Shannon': ['Cannon']}

for k, v in d.items():
    d[k] = set(v)

print(d)
```

**Output**

```
{'Donald Knuth': {'Donut'}, 'Claude Shannon': {'Cannon'}, 'Alan Turing': {'Anting', 'Alanin'}}
```

Comment: okay, but even better/alternate one-liner with a dict comprehension: `{k:set(v) for k,v in my_dict.items()}`

Comment: Yeah that looks a lot better.

Comment: that's good to provide both variants. Some people are allergic to dictcomps :)

Comment: Even without dictcomps, you can write `dict((k,set(v)) for k, v in my_dict.items())`.

Comment: Is there any more efficient way to do so?